# Bootloader Grub2 - delete partition where ubuntu resides

Tags: ubuntu, partition, grub2

I have a dualboot with the following two Os's:

```
Windows10
Kubuntu
```

And the bootloader

```
Grub2
```

What happends with the bootloader if I delete/formats the partition where Kubuntu is installed? Does it detect this and deletes the *ubuntu from the list? See attached image!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Grub is installed by linux, kubuntu in your case. Thus, if you remove ubuntu you'll lose your bootloader.
Then you'd need to use a recovery cd to get your win10 back.
I guess you should first fix your bootmanager, i.e. stop calling grub2 at boot time, from windows ; then only remove your kubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where your grub2 repository is installed.
And if your installation is fine, it will be on your boot partition (dev/sda1 for you). If it's not here, well I'll delete my post because you will have too learn how manage [grub2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB) but i don't think that you want to. You can try rEFInd if you want something more easy to config.

So when you'll erase Ubuntu, nothing will append, except that when you try to run Ubuntu, you won't. And you will no longer have some command line access on it (I never use them).

If you want to remove the Ubuntu entry on you grub2, just find your `grub.cfg` (probably there : `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`)
It will looks like [that](http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20Configuration%20File%20Commands.html), then remove all section `Menuentry 'Ubuntu...'` (not just the line).

If you install another Linux distribution, then be careful and copy your `grub.cfg` (because it will probably be erased). Like this you'll be able to copy the Menuentry section for Window of your old file into the new one (don't touch your Window partition, or it won't be the same config).